# How to include ignition math library in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am not sure if this is the right platform to ask this question, but I know that ignition math has been forked from Gazebosim project. For a personal project, I want to use ignition math library from https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/math/5.0/tutorials.html. I am not sure how to put include this library in CMakeLists.txt so that my Makefile generated from `cmake .` may able to build my project.

Can anyone help me in this manner?

Currently, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ACE)

#The Version number
set (ACE_VERSION MAJOR 0)
set (ACE_VERSION MINOR 1)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

# Need to have these in order to find/include boost stuff
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

include_directories(include
src
)

add_executable(ACE ace.cpp
include/ACEConstant.h
include/ACETypes.h
include/ACEGrid.h
include/util.h
src/ACEGrid.cpp
src/util.cpp
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22598/how-to-include-ignition-math-library-in-cmakelists.txt?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ignition math provides cmake package configuration files so, assuming you're using version 6, you can call `find_package(ignition-math6 REQUIRED)` and link against the library via `target_link_libraries(ACE ignition-math6::ignition-math6)`

You can find an example CMakeLists.txt file at https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-math/src/default/examples/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adlarkin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38815/adlarkin/) on 2020-12-18**:
It looks like the example `CMakeLists.txt` link is no longer working, since the Ignition project moved to GitHub. Here's an updated link to an example `CMakeLists.txt`: https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-math/blob/ign-math6/examples/CMakeLists.txt